How does the lifetime and temperature of a black hole scale with mass in universe with more then 3 spacial dimensions?
I've tried to find out how the lifetime and temperature of a black hole scale with mass in a universe with more then 3 spatial dimensions. I've spent a while trying to look up an answer to this question but the few papers I've found don't clearly state an answer.

Can you link the papers you found?

Consider a Schwarzschild black hole in $d\ge3$ space dimensions. Write power laws as $X\propto M^{\left[X\right]}$. The Schwarzschild radius $R$, Hawking temperature $T$, surface gravity $g$, rate of mass decay $-\dot{M}$ and lifetime $\tau$ satisfy$$\begin{align}\left[R\right]&=\frac{1}{d-2},\\\left[T\right]&=\left[g\right]\\&=\left[MR^{1-d}\right]\\&=\left[R^{-1}\right]\\&=\frac{-1}{d-2},\\\left[-\dot{M}\right]&=\left(d-1\right)\left[R\right]+\left(d+1\right)\left[T\right]\\&=\frac{-2}{d-2},\\\left[\tau\right]&=\left[M\right]-\left[-\dot{M}\right]\\&=\frac{d}{d-2}.\end{align}$$The case $d=3$ is a sanity check.
